# get all details of validation after each epoch in training with keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification

I use keras `ImageDataGenerator` and `fit_generator` to train my images. After each epoch, the validation_loss and the validation_accuracy is printed on the console. Now **is there an option in keras to print the datails of the validation on all the validation data**?

For example I have 100 images in 5 class, as the validation data. Assume the val_loss after the first epoch is 75%, now I want to know which of those images got classified wrong and which is classified correct (in every  epoch).

I know I can test all the validation data with `model.predict()` one by one, but I need to get this prediction (validation) result in every epoch.

Comment: Hey Meisam, maybe [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2548) will help?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503857/how-i-can-print-the-output-arrays-for-each-iteration-of-each-iteration-in-traini) person solved something similar, check the comments and try that.

Comment: @SajanGohil that wasn't what I need but thanks for the suggestion.